# Kickstarting an Ubuntu Server 10.04 installation (DHCP fails)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp, kickstart

I'm trying to automate the network installation of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with an anaconda kickstart and everything seems to running except for the initial DHCP autoconfiguration.  The installer attempts to configure the install via DHCP but fails on its first attempt.  This brings me to a prompt where I can retry DHCP and it seems to always work on the second attempt.  My issue is that this is not really automated if I have to hit retry for DHCP.  Is there something I can add to the kickstart file so that it will automatically retry or better yet not fail the first time? Thanks.

Kickstart:

```
# System language
lang en_US
# Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
# System keyboard
keyboard us
# System mouse
mouse
# System timezone
timezone America/New_York
# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$unrsWyF2$B0W.k2h1roBSSFmUDsW0r/
# Initial user
user --disabled
# Reboot after installation
reboot
# Use text mode install
text
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# Use Web installation
url --url=http://10.16.0.1/cobbler/ks_mirror/ubuntu-10.04-x86_64/
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
# Disk partitioning information
part swap --size 512 
part / --fstype ext3 --size 1 --grow 
# System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
%include /tmp/pre_install_ubuntu_network_config

# Always install the server kernel.
preseed --owner d-i     base-installer/kernel/override-image    string linux-server
# Install the Ubuntu Server seed.
preseed --owner tasksel tasksel/force-tasks     string server

# Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled 
# Do not configure the X Window System
skipx

%pre

wget "http://10.16.0.1/cblr/svc/op/trig/mode/pre/system/Test-D" -O /dev/null
# Network information
# Start pre_install_network_config generated code

# Start of code to match cobbler system interfaces to physical interfaces by their mac addresses
#  Start eth0
# Configuring eth0 (00:1A:64:36:B1:C8)
if ip -o link show | grep -i 00:1A:64:36:B1:C8
then
  IFNAME=$(ip -o link show | grep -i 00:1A:64:36:B1:C8 | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d :)
  echo "network --device=$IFNAME --bootproto=dhcp" >> /tmp/pre_install_ubuntu_network_config
fi
# End pre_install_network_config generated code


%packages
openssh-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Include a line like this:

```
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
```

before the %pre section.